# Struts 2 tag lib for number textfield

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have this code in a JSP page using Struts 2 Framework to get a number.

```
<s:textfield type="number" name="year">
```

How can I specify the min, max value and step of this field like in HTML5?

```
<input type="number" name="year" min="2010" max="2018" step="2"/>
```

Comment: Next time please try it before posting a question about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by HTML 5 attributes as it is in `<s:textfield>`.

```html
<s:textfield type="number" name="year" min="2010" max="2018" step="2"/>
```

Or try to use dynamic attribute in .tld.

```html
<dynamic-attributes>true</dynamic-attributes>
```